# Explicit formula for Fibonacci numbers; compositions of $n$

Tags: reference-request, enumerative-combinatorics, fibonacci-numbers

A *Fibonacci-type sequence* is a sequence with two seed-values, $F_1$ and $F_2$, and which, for all $n>2$, abides by the recurrence relation $F_n = F_{n-1} + F_{n-2}$. If $F_1 = F_2 = s$, then the $n$th number is equal to the number of compositions of $n-1$, consisting only of $1$'s and $2$'s, multiplied by $s$:

$$\begin{align} F_n = \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor (n-1)/2\rfloor} \binom{\lfloor (n-1)/2\rfloor+k}{2k+1} s  \end{align} $$

I also have a similar kind of formula for when $F_1 \ne F_2$ that uses the exact same technique (counting compositions that is), though I chose not include it here for brevity's sake.

So, my question is  the following; **has this result been found before?** I know that people know about the link between compositions of $n-1$ and the $n$th Fibonacci number (it's mentioned on Wikipedia), but have people found this formula? I would think so, but I haven't found it when Googling.

**NB:** If you have $F_0 = 0$, that amounts to $F_1 = F_2$, which means the above formula still stands even though, technically, the seed-values aren't equal.

Comment: This looks standard; as a start, Mathematica can rewrite the right hand side: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Sum%5BBinomial%5Bm%2Bk%2C2k%2B1%5D%2C%7Bk%2C0%2Cm%7D%5D

Comment: One well-known formula for Fibonaccis as sums of binomials can be found at https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Fibonacci_Number_as_Sum_of_Binomial_Coefficients

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this identity is well known.  According to Singh's [The so-called Fibonacci numbers in ancient and medieval India](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0315086085900217), the $s=1$ case has been known since at least the the 14th century.  Since everything in the sequence with $F_1 = F_2 = s$ is a multiple of $s$, the formula for that case follows immediately.

Your Fibonacci-type sequence is known in the literature as generalized Fibonacci sequences or, in Art Benjamin & Jenny Quinn's wonderful book [*Proofs that Really Count*](https://bookstore.ams.org/dol-27/), Gibonacci numbers.  Their Identity 4 is the $s=1$ case of your formula, proven combinatorially with square and domino tilings, equivalently compositions restricted to parts 1 and 2 (an interpretation Singh suggests was known some time BCE).  With $F_1 = F_2 = s$, the parts are restricted to $s$ and $2s$ analogously.

Comment: Thank you. I assume then that the equivalent formula for when $F_1 \ne F_2$ is also known?

Comment: @user1113719: See Combinatorial Theorem 3 in §2.3 of the Benjamin/Quinn book cited by Brian. Alternatively, combine Propositions 4.9.18 and 4.9.19 in [my Math 235 notes from Fall 2020](https://www.cip.ifi.lmu.de/~grinberg/t/20f/mps.pdf).